# Swift button only showing in dark mode

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I am adding a button in a tableview section header, and it currently only shows while my phone is in dark mode, I have no idea what the issue might be. All other elements in the header show in both light and dark mode.

`headerHeight` is a static 200 pixels

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: headerHeight))
    
    let imageButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: view.frame.width / 2 - 50, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100))
    imageButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "person.crop.circle"), for: .normal)
    view.addSubview(imageButton)
    
    let nameButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 110, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 40))
    nameButton.tintColor = .label
    nameButton.titleLabel?.textColor = .label
    nameButton.setTitle("Set Name", for: .normal)
    nameButton.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    view.addSubview(nameButton)
    
    let accountsLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 175, width: 80, height: 20))
    accountsLabel.text = "Accounts"
    accountsLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 15)
    view.addSubview(accountsLabel)
    
    return view
}
```

Comment: didn't set one, there is another button I created that is showing just fine in both light and dark mode

Comment: Same thing happens when I don't set it to ```.label``` color

Comment: just posted the whole function

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
nameButton.titleLabel?.textColor = .label
```

That is not how you set a button's title color. Change it to:

```
nameButton.setTitleColor(.label, for: .normal)
```